# How to override Liferay core' css?

Tags: css, liferay, liferay-ide

Hi there i'm want to override a data picker css from a hook creation.
In Liferay Documentation 6.2 they say that it's possible with hook.

http://www.liferay.com/it/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/overriding-web-resources-with-hook-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-en

But in Liferay IDE, when I create a new hook, in the interface for xml liferay-hook there isn't an option for CSS.

There are:

- Portal properties
- Custom JSP
- Service Wrappers
- Filter and Mappings
- Struts Action
- Indexer Post Processors
- Language properties

So, how to make it? Thanks ahead!

Comment: If your css changes are less then you can add css in control panel > site pages.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it's an important option!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a plugin: THEME. You can see how in this page:
https://www.liferay.com/es/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/creating-themes-and-layout-templates-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-09-en
In this plugin you have a folder _diffs. Everything you put here is going to overwrite liferay´s theme.